# How do I just grep a column in my ksh script?

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

The following is my code:

```
#!/bin/ksh -p
NAME=$1
echo $NAME likes to drink:
grep $NAME ~/practice/database/likes
echo total number of beers $NAME likes to drink:
grep $NAME ~/practice/database/likes | wc -l
```

The following is my output:

```
dave likes to drink:
dave,coors
dave,bud
total number of beers dave likes to drink:
       2
```

How do I just output "coors" and "bud"?

Comment: What does this have to do with vi?

Comment: because this script is in vi

Comment: It's in ksh from the looks of it.

Comment: My fault, it is a kornshell script, I just thought vi script was the proper terminology because is being written in vi...my apologies Im very new to this...im just a scholar

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
grep $NAME ~/practice/database/likes | awk -F, '{ print $2 }'
```

or

```
grep $NAME ~/practice/database/likes | cut -d , -f 2
```

[man awk](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/awk/)

[man cut](http://ss64.com/bash/cut.html)

Comment: Thank you.  the second statement was the original one I was looking for...I would vote you up but dont have 15 reputation yet...Just started UNIX and this account....Im just a scholar

Answer (score 0):

If you use `sed` then you only need one program:

```
sed 's/'$NAME',//'  ~/practice/database/likes
```

or you could use `awk`, but don't use `grep` with it because `awk` is capable of regular expresions as well:

```
awk -F, '/'$NAME'/{ print $2 }' ~/practice/database/likes
```

Comment: I dont have 15 reputation yet so I cant vote you up.  The second statement worked.  The first one didn't work.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JeffOrris:  exactly what happened when you tried the first statement?